# How do I set up a virtualenv that I've inherited

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, virtualenv

I've inherited a virtualenv and need help getting it running on MacOSX. There's no documentation provided so I'm not sure if it is complete, but need help getting it going. I need help making sure the virtualenv is complete with all dependencies, database, etc.

Project should be:
Python 2.7
Django 1.3
PostgreSQL

Looks lik I can get the virtualenv activated by:

```
$ cd app
$ source bin/activate
```

However, doesn't look like it's using Python from within the virtualenv:

```
$ which python 
/usr/bin/python
```

I've also tried:

```
echo $PATH
/virtualenv/app/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

$ pip freeze lists out global packages, not ones originating from within the virtualenv

Thanks in advance.

Here are the directories and files contained within the virtualenv:

```
 |-app
 |---bin
 |---include
 |-----python2.7
 |---lib
 |-----Django-1.3
 |-------django
 |---------bin
 |-----------profiling
 |---------conf
 |-----------app_template
 |-----------locale
 |-----------project_template
 |-----------urls
 |---------contrib
 |-----------admin
 |-------------locale
 |-------------media
 |---------------css
 |---------------img
 |-----------------admin
 |-----------------gis
 |---------------js
 |-----------------admin
 |-------------templates
 |---------------admin
 |-----------------auth
 |-------------------user
 |-----------------edit_inline
 |-----------------includes
 |---------------registration
 |-------------templatetags
 |-------------views
 |-----------admindocs
 |-------------locale
 |-------------templates
 |---------------admin_doc
 |-------------tests
 |-----------auth
 |-------------fixtures
 |-------------handlers
 |-------------locale
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-------------tests
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------registration
 |-----------comments
 |-------------locale
 |-------------templates
 |---------------comments
 |-------------templatetags
 |-------------views
 |-----------contenttypes
 |-------------locale
 |-----------csrf
 |-----------databrowse
 |-------------plugins
 |-------------templates
 |---------------databrowse
 |-----------flatpages
 |-------------fixtures
 |-------------locale
 |-------------templatetags
 |-------------tests
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------flatpages
 |-----------------registration
 |-----------formtools
 |-------------locale
 |-------------templates
 |---------------formtools
 |-------------tests
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------formwizard
 |-----------gis
 |-------------admin
 |-------------db
 |---------------backend
 |---------------backends
 |-----------------mysql
 |-----------------oracle
 |-----------------postgis
 |-----------------spatialite
 |---------------models
 |-----------------sql
 |-------------forms
 |-------------gdal
 |---------------prototypes
 |---------------tests
 |-------------geometry
 |---------------backend
 |-------------geos
 |---------------prototypes
 |---------------tests
 |-------------locale
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-------------maps
 |---------------google
 |---------------openlayers
 |-------------sitemaps
 |-------------templates
 |---------------gis
 |-----------------admin
 |-----------------google
 |-----------------kml
 |-----------------sitemaps
 |-------------utils
 |-----------humanize
 |-------------templatetags
 |-----------localflavor
 |-----------markup
 |-------------templatetags
 |-----------messages
 |-------------locale
 |-------------storage
 |-------------tests
 |-----------redirects
 |-------------locale
 |-----------sessions
 |-------------backends
 |-------------locale
 |-----------sitemaps
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-------------templates
 |-------------tests
 |---------------templates
 |-----------sites
 |-------------locale
 |-----------staticfiles
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-----------syndication
 |-----------webdesign
 |-------------templatetags
 |---------core
 |-----------cache
 |-------------backends
 |-----------files
 |-----------handlers
 |-----------mail
 |-------------backends
 |-----------management
 |-------------commands
 |-----------serializers
 |-----------servers
 |---------db
 |-----------backends
 |-------------dummy
 |-------------mysql
 |-------------oracle
 |-------------postgresql
 |-------------postgresql_psycopg2
 |-------------sqlite3
 |-----------models
 |-------------fields
 |-------------sql
 |---------dispatch
 |---------forms
 |-----------extras
 |---------http
 |---------middleware
 |---------shortcuts
 |---------template
 |-----------loaders
 |---------templatetags
 |---------test
 |---------utils
 |-----------simplejson
 |-----------translation
 |-----------unittest
 |---------views
 |-----------decorators
 |-----------generic
 |-------docs
 |---------_ext
 |---------_theme
 |-----------djangodocs
 |-------------static
 |---------faq
 |---------howto
 |-----------deployment
 |---------internals
 |-----------_images
 |---------intro
 |-----------_images
 |---------man
 |---------misc
 |---------obsolete
 |-----------_images
 |---------ref
 |-----------contrib
 |-------------admin
 |---------------_images
 |-------------comments
 |-------------formtools
 |-------------gis
 |-----------files
 |-----------forms
 |-----------models
 |-----------templates
 |---------releases
 |---------topics
 |-----------db
 |-----------forms
 |-----------http
 |-------------_images
 |-----------i18n
 |-------extras
 |-------scripts
 |-------tests
 |---------modeltests
 |-----------aggregation
 |-------------fixtures
 |-----------basic
 |-----------choices
 |-----------custom_columns
 |-----------custom_managers
 |-----------custom_methods
 |-----------custom_pk
 |-----------defer
 |-----------delete
 |-----------empty
 |-----------expressions
 |-----------field_defaults
 |-----------field_subclassing
 |-----------files
 |-----------fixtures
 |-------------fixtures
 |-----------fixtures_model_package
 |-------------fixtures
 |-------------models
 |-----------force_insert_update
 |-----------generic_relations
 |-----------get_latest
 |-----------get_object_or_404
 |-----------get_or_create
 |-----------invalid_models
 |-----------lookup
 |-----------m2m_and_m2o
 |-----------m2m_intermediary
 |-----------m2m_multiple
 |-----------m2m_recursive
 |-----------m2m_signals
 |-----------m2m_through
 |-----------m2o_recursive
 |-----------many_to_many
 |-----------many_to_one
 |-----------many_to_one_null
 |-----------model_forms
 |-----------model_formsets
 |-----------model_inheritance
 |-----------model_inheritance_same_model_name
 |-----------model_package
 |-------------models
 |-----------mutually_referential
 |-----------one_to_one
 |-----------or_lookups
 |-----------order_with_respect_to
 |-----------ordering
 |-----------pagination
 |-----------properties
 |-----------proxy_model_inheritance
 |-------------app1
 |-------------app2
 |-----------proxy_models
 |-------------fixtures
 |-----------raw_query
 |-------------fixtures
 |-----------reserved_names
 |-----------reverse_lookup
 |-----------save_delete_hooks
 |-----------select_related
 |-----------serializers
 |-----------signals
 |-----------str
 |-----------test_client
 |-------------fixtures
 |-----------transactions
 |-----------unmanaged_models
 |-----------update
 |-----------user_commands
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-----------validation
 |-----------validators
 |---------regressiontests
 |---------templates
 |-----------comments
 |-----------custom_admin
 |-----------views
 |-----python2.7
 |-------config
 |-------distutils
 |-------encodings
 |-------lib-dynload
 |-------site-packages
 |---------Django-1.3.7-py2.7.egg-info
 |---------MySQLdb
 |-----------constants
 |---------PIL
 |---------_markerlib
 |---------django-
 |-----------bin
 |-------------profiling
 |-----------conf
 |-------------app_template
 |-------------locale
 |-------------project_template
 |-------------urls
 |-----------contrib
 |-------------admin
 |---------------locale
 |---------------media
 |-----------------css
 |-----------------img
 |-------------------admin
 |-------------------gis
 |-----------------js
 |-------------------admin
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------admin
 |-------------------auth
 |---------------------user
 |-------------------edit_inline
 |-------------------includes
 |-----------------registration
 |---------------templatetags
 |---------------views
 |-------------admindocs
 |---------------locale
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------admin_doc
 |---------------tests
 |-------------auth
 |---------------fixtures
 |---------------handlers
 |---------------locale
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |---------------tests
 |-----------------templates
 |-------------------registration
 |-------------comments
 |---------------locale
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------comments
 |---------------templatetags
 |---------------views
 |-------------contenttypes
 |---------------locale
 |-------------csrf
 |-------------databrowse
 |---------------plugins
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------databrowse
 |-------------flatpages
 |---------------fixtures
 |---------------locale
 |---------------templatetags
 |---------------tests
 |-----------------templates
 |-------------------flatpages
 |-------------------registration
 |-------------formtools
 |---------------locale
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------formtools
 |---------------tests
 |-----------------templates
 |-------------------formwizard
 |-------------gis
 |---------------admin
 |---------------db
 |-----------------backend
 |-----------------backends
 |-------------------mysql
 |-------------------oracle
 |-------------------postgis
 |-------------------spatialite
 |-----------------models
 |-------------------sql
 |---------------forms
 |---------------gdal
 |-----------------prototypes
 |-----------------tests
 |---------------geometry
 |-----------------backend
 |---------------geos
 |-----------------prototypes
 |-----------------tests
 |---------------locale
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |---------------maps
 |-----------------google
 |-----------------openlayers
 |---------------sitemaps
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------gis
 |-------------------admin
 |-------------------google
 |-------------------kml
 |-------------------sitemaps
 |---------------tests
 |-----------------data
 |-------------------cities
 |-------------------counties
 |-------------------interstates
 |-------------------invalid
 |-------------------test_point
 |-------------------test_poly
 |-------------------test_vrt
 |-----------------distapp
 |-------------------fixtures
 |-----------------geo3d
 |-----------------geoapp
 |-------------------fixtures
 |-----------------geogapp
 |-------------------fixtures
 |-----------------layermap
 |-----------------relatedapp
 |-------------------fixtures
 |---------------utils
 |-------------humanize
 |---------------locale
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------localflavor
 |---------------locale
 |-------------markup
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------messages
 |---------------locale
 |---------------storage
 |---------------tests
 |-------------redirects
 |---------------locale
 |-------------sessions
 |---------------backends
 |---------------locale
 |-------------sitemaps
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |---------------templates
 |---------------tests
 |-----------------templates
 |-------------sites
 |---------------locale
 |-------------staticfiles
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |-------------syndication
 |-------------webdesign
 |---------------templatetags
 |-----------core
 |-------------cache
 |---------------backends
 |-------------files
 |-------------handlers
 |-------------mail
 |---------------backends
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-------------serializers
 |-------------servers
 |-----------db
 |-------------backends
 |---------------dummy
 |---------------mysql
 |---------------oracle
 |---------------postgresql
 |---------------postgresql_psycopg2
 |---------------sqlite3
 |-------------models
 |---------------fields
 |---------------sql
 |-----------dispatch
 |-----------forms
 |-------------extras
 |-----------http
 |-----------middleware
 |-----------shortcuts
 |-----------template
 |-------------loaders
 |-----------templatetags
 |-----------test
 |-----------utils
 |-------------simplejson
 |-------------translation
 |-------------unittest
 |-----------views
 |-------------decorators
 |-------------generic
 |---------django-live
 |-----------bin
 |-------------profiling
 |-----------conf
 |-------------app_template
 |-------------locale
 |-------------project_template
 |-------------urls
 |-----------contrib
 |-------------admin
 |---------------media
 |-----------------css
 |-----------------img
 |-------------------admin
 |-------------------gis
 |-----------------js
 |-------------------admin
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------admin
 |-------------------auth
 |---------------------user
 |-------------------edit_inline
 |-------------------includes
 |-----------------registration
 |---------------templatetags
 |---------------views
 |-------------admindocs
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------admin_doc
 |---------------tests
 |-------------auth
 |---------------fixtures
 |---------------handlers
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |-------------comments
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------comments
 |---------------templatetags
 |---------------views
 |-------------contenttypes
 |-------------csrf
 |-------------databrowse
 |---------------plugins
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------databrowse
 |-------------flatpages
 |-------------formtools
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------formtools
 |-------------gis
 |---------------admin
 |---------------db
 |-----------------backend
 |-----------------backends
 |-------------------mysql
 |-------------------oracle
 |-------------------postgis
 |-------------------spatialite
 |-----------------models
 |-------------------sql
 |---------------forms
 |---------------gdal
 |-----------------prototypes
 |-----------------tests
 |---------------geometry
 |-----------------backend
 |---------------geos
 |-----------------prototypes
 |-----------------tests
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |---------------maps
 |-----------------google
 |-----------------openlayers
 |---------------sitemaps
 |---------------templates
 |-----------------gis
 |-------------------admin
 |-------------------google
 |-------------------kml
 |-------------------sitemaps
 |---------------utils
 |-------------humanize
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------localflavor
 |-------------markup
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------messages
 |---------------storage
 |---------------tests
 |-------------redirects
 |-------------sessions
 |---------------backends
 |-------------sitemaps
 |---------------management
 |-----------------commands
 |---------------templates
 |-------------sites
 |-------------syndication
 |-------------webdesign
 |---------------templatetags
 |-----------core
 |-------------cache
 |---------------backends
 |-------------files
 |-------------handlers
 |-------------mail
 |---------------backends
 |-------------management
 |---------------commands
 |-------------serializers
 |-------------servers
 |-----------db
 |-------------backends
 |---------------dummy
 |---------------mysql
 |---------------oracle
 |---------------postgresql
 |---------------postgresql_psycopg2
 |---------------sqlite3
 |-------------models
 |---------------fields
 |---------------sql
 |-----------dispatch
 |-----------forms
 |-------------extras
 |-----------http
 |-----------middleware
 |-----------shortcuts
 |-----------template
 |-------------loaders
 |-----------templatetags
 |-----------test
 |-----------utils
 |-------------simplejson
 |-------------translation
 |-----------views
 |-------------decorators
 |-------------generic
 |---------docutils
 |-----------languages
 |-----------parsers
 |-------------rst
 |---------------directives
 |---------------include
 |---------------languages
 |-----------readers
 |-------------python
 |-----------transforms
 |-----------writers
 |-------------html4css1
 |-------------latex2e
 |-------------newlatex2e
 |-------------odf_odt
 |-------------pep_html
 |-------------s5_html
 |---------------themes
 |---------docutils-0.7-py2.6.egg-info
 |---------goshkihy
 |-----------about
 |-------------migrations
 |-----------gallery
 |-------------migrations
 |-----------news
 |-------------migrations
 |-----------templates
 |-------------about
 |-------------admin
 |---------------menu
 |---------gunicorn
 |-----------app
 |-----------http
 |-----------management
 |-------------commands
 |-----------workers
 |---------gunicorn-18.0-py2.7.egg-info
 |---------client
 |-----------br
 |-------------gallery
 |-------------memory
 |---------------migrations
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------utils
 |-----------goshkihy
 |-------------about
 |---------------migrations
 |-------------gallery
 |---------------migrations
 |-------------news
 |---------------migrations
 |-------------templates
 |---------------about
 |---------------admin
 |-----------------menu
 |---------------admin_doc
 |---------------employment
 |---------------events
 |---------------experience
 |---------------flatpages
 |---------------generic
 |---------------menu
 |-----------restaurant
 |-------------employment
 |---------------migrations
 |-------------event
 |---------------migrations
 |-------------location
 |---------------migrations
 |---------------templatetags
 |-------------menu
 |---------------migrations
 |---------multilingual
 |-----------flatpages
 |-------------templates
 |---------------flatpages
 |-------------templatetags
 |-----------management
 |-------------commands
 |-----------media
 |-------------multilingual
 |---------------admin
 |-----------------css
 |-----------templates
 |-------------admin
 |---------------multilingual
 |-----------------edit_inline
 |-----------templatetags
 |---------pip
 |-----------backwardcompat
 |-----------commands
 |-----------vcs
 |-----------vendor
 |-------------distlib
 |---------------_backport
 |-------------html5lib
 |---------pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg
 |-----------EGG-INFO
 |-----------pip
 |-------------commands
 |-------------vcs
 |---------pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
 |---------psycopg2
 |---------psycopg2--
 |---------psycopg2-2.0.10-py2.7.egg-info
 |---------restaurant
 |-----------employment
 |-------------migrations
 |-----------event
 |-------------migrations
 |-----------location
 |-------------migrations
 |-------------templatetags
 |-----------menu
 |-------------migrations
 |---------setuptools
 |-----------_backport
 |-------------hashlib
 |-----------command
 |-----------tests
 |---------setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info
 |---------south
 |-----------creator
 |-----------db
 |-------------sql_server
 |-----------hacks
 |-----------introspection_plugins
 |-----------management
 |-------------commands
 |-----------migration
 |---run
 |-bin
 |-docs
 |---_theme
 |-----nature
 |-------static
 |-scripts
 |-virtualenv.egg-info
 |-virtualenv_embedded
 |-virtualenv_support
```

Comment: Did it not include a requirements file?

Comment: Also try `which python2` instead of `which python`.

Comment: How did you "inherit" this virtualenv? Where was it stored and how did you get it onto your machine?

Comment: 1. It did not include a requirements.txt file within what I thought was the virtualenv. There was a requirements.txt file that I found outside of this directory.

Comment: 2. After activating the virtualenv, trying `$ which python2` produced no result.`$ which python3` produces `/usr/local/bin/python3` while `$ which python` continues to produce `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: 3. How I inherited the virtualenv: It was included within a complete cPanel backup I had created on the exhisting web host. I then installed the cPanel backup on a new server. The virtualenv in question was just one of a few that I located.